# How can I have a parameter with slashes in gin url

Tags: go, go-gin

I want to have a parameter with slashes in the router in gin.

From what I gathered I can do this by adding a wildcard to the URL. For example: `/api/v0/files/*addr`

But this approach doesn't work if I want to have the `addr` in the middle of the URL like `/api/v0/*addr/files`, and it returns this error:

> catch-all routes are only allowed at the end of the path.

I was wondering whether there is another way of having it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that is a limitation of the Gin framework, as seen @ https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/tree.go#L322

You could always invert the order and do a rewrite using a proxy and a regexp (i.e. /api/v0/*addr/files to /api/v0/files/*addr) or only accept methods ending with /files inside your handling function, but I'm afraid that is a hardcoded limitation of the Gin framework.